# mssql_connect in PHP does not exist

Tags: php, sql-server, database

I've been struggling with this for a while now and I don't know what I'm missing. The error is:

```
call to undefined function mssql_connect()
```

Having looked into it already, I've done about everything I can.

- I moved the `php.ini` file to `c:\windows`
- In the ini I changed the `extension_dir` directive to `c:PHP\ext` and uncommented:

  ```
  extension = php_mssql.dll
  ```
- I moved the dll file to `c:windows\system32\`
- I downloaded the 200.80.194.0 version of ntwdblib.dll and placed it in `c:\windows\system32`
- I restarted my web server client

PHP is still not recognizing the function and library classes. I'm stumped as to what I didn't do right and would love some help. If it's helpful, I'm running PHP 5.3.2, IIS, and Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Sorry just to clarify further none of the files were moved. They were copied and moved so most are in 2 places. Their original place and where I've said they were moved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For SQL Server 2008 on Windows it's `sqlsrv_connect` This is because Microsoft now uses the [SQL Driver for PHP](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=df4d9cc9-459c-4d75-a503-ae3fceb85860&displaylang=en) which is now on version 2.0 I believe.

Also it's worth noting that with sqlsrv_query, and mssql_query they switched the parameters around (spent half an hour figuring that out).

Answer (score 2):

You say you are running PHP 5.3.2. The PHP manual states:

> This extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or later.

The PHP MSSQL library is ancient and is no longer considered a viable option.

You should instead examine [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) with either the [MSSQL driver](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php) or the more reliable [ODBC driver](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php).

Microsoft are still developing their own PDO driver. [Version 2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=df4d9cc9-459c-4d75-a503-ae3fceb85860&displaylang=en) was made available June 2010. Microsoft recommend the more stable [version 1.1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ccdf728b-1ea0-48a8-a84a-5052214caad9&displaylang=en) for production use.

Comment: thank you very much. this appears to be solving that specific problem.