# Error in function mssql_connect()

Tags: php, sql-server, fatal-error

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mssql_connect in php does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104921/mssql-connect-in-php-does-not-exist)

How to solve the following error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in /var/www/delhunt/MSSQLTest.php on line 8

Comment: Make sure you have the MSSQL extension installed an enabled.  Check the output of `phpinfo()`

Answer (score 3):

You have to enable `msssql` functions from the `php.ini` file and check for `php_mssql.dll`  in the php extensions folder

Comment: Please move your answer over to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104921/mssql-connect-in-php-does-not-exist