# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() PHP5.5

Tags: php, apache, web-services, sql-server-2008

I am currently migrating a Drupal site for local development. One of the custom modules is throwing an error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()

I installed the MS SQL PHP Driver and included it in php.ini

> extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
>   extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll

However, the error still persists. How can I fix it? the dll's above are for the right version of PHP (5.5.31)

Comment: Did you restart the web server after you installed them? Did you modify the *right* php.ini (there could be more than one)?

Comment: Yes. Multiple times.

Comment: Also, yes, I checked which one is being loaded using the phpinfo()

Comment: Which one is being loaded?

Comment: I am running AMPPS and the file is Loaded Configuration File C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\apache\php.ini

Comment: Did you install `Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 (or higher) for SQL Server Client` as well. That is also required

Comment: No I have not. I was actually able to get this working yesterday with the same extensions. However, today it seems broken.

Comment: Can be downloaded here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt703139%28v=sql.1%29.aspx

Comment: I have installed it. Should I expect everything to start working or are there settings to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mssql\_connect in PHP does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104921/mssql-connect-in-php-does-not-exist)